# applying css value right after some value

Tags: jquery

I have styled my css like this

```
.mycss{border: 2px solid; background: url("") no-repeat;}
```

how could I add `#f00` right after **solid** and right after **no-repeat** with a space with jquery?

**Edit**
What if I would like to edit my css with js?

Comment: Where is your CSS? In the document itself or in a stylesheet? And *why* are you parsing/adapting your styles with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: I would like to do it once.

Comment: What if I would like to edit my css with js?

Comment: then you can add a style tag with jquery for examlpe:  `$('head').append(<style type=..>your css goes here</style>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this:

```
.mycss:hover{border: #f00; background-color: #f00;}
```

and it will do what you want you can add it rightin your css or your html page as a `style` tag there is no need to use js or jq for this, and it will add them to this css because you are adding something not editting :D

Comment: background: #f00; will override the image.

Comment: then you can be more specific: `background-color: #f00;`

Answer (score 0):

Use [specific CSS properties for color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

```
background-color: #f00
```

That will not override `background-image` or `background-position`. For border there is `border-color` property.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, css is the way to go. But, if you still want to use jQuery, here's a way you could do this.

- Add a class with the styles you want to add when hovering.

  ```
  .onHover {
      border-color: #f00;
      background-color : #f00
   }
  ```
- Then you could use the `hover` event of jQuery and `toggle` the class whenever hovering.

  ```
   $(".mycss").hover(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("onHover");
   });
  ```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/gU7Zp/